# A remedial lesson for those who have VTC powers

Tags: discussion

This is not worded as a question. I do not intend it to be one. You need to refrain from slandering questions that you do not like as a "list question" just so you can close them.

If the person asks "what is the term for an animal occupation stereotype" this is not a list question even if in the body they explain that they will take the answer and use it to search for a list elsewhere.

I will not mention my own question that people call a "list question" despite it clearly stating that a correct answer would be a single item.

Questions that you do not like are not automatically list questions. That it will get more than one answer from more than one person will not make it a list question. Please stop and have some sense.

Comment: Maybe opening with misuse of the word "slander" is not the best way to convey this message.

Comment: Meta is for constructive discussions, not rants. As such, I'll be deleting this when I get around to it in the morning unless you rephrase it in a more constructive manner. Also, I'm quite sure I've seen a meta post about whether we should allow superlative questions (what was the earliest/most/biggest/etc.). If you can find that, you can either see why the questions in question were closed or use it to (constructively) contest their closing.  If you have further concerns, ping me in chat.

Comment: How can I rephrase it better? You have people abusing VTC, do something about it. I'd flag them, but VTCs are anonmyous and unflaggable.

Comment: Keep an eye on it, if it actually gets closed bring it up on meta or use a custom flag to explain clearly (preferably with a link to a meta discussion on the topic) why it should be reopened.

Comment: @JohnO VTC's are not 100% anonymous. As far as I can tell, votes done directly from the question's page is anonymous (unless it is cast for a successful close reason), but votes done via the review tool are logged and visible in [the review history viewer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) (note: this may be an locked privilege)

Comment: `I will not mention my own question that people call a "list question" despite it clearly stating that a correct answer would be a single item` I have no idea what your question was, but a correct answer consisting of a single item can still be a list question, if there are a large number of *possible* single correct answers. This has been discussed quite a few times in meta. I'm not sure if your question fell into this category or not, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: **<Comments removed>**  Keep comments on point of discussing how to improve the question.  If you have an argument to make on the topic this question discusses, post an answer.

Comment: As written, this is not an attempt to encourage discussion or seek clarification of any sort. It is purely a rant.

Answer (score 3):

The question you are referring to has the following in its body:

> ...**I want to find a list** of stereotypical anthropomorphic animals.
>
> ...Is there a term for this? **Is there a list** of these stereotypes?

**"Is there a list"** very **clearly** is asking for a list.

That being said, looking at the non-list portion of the question, which was essentially the title: ["What is the term for an anthropomorphic animal that fits a certain role or profession?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37833/what-is-the-term-for-an-anthropomorphic-animal-that-fits-a-certain-role-or-profe) the question doesn't seem (IMO) to fit well on scifi.SE, but rather would fit better on English.SE (given the closing of Literature.SE). The OP would benefit best from experts in literature and the English language. The only answers it has received thus far here are list answers, which we do not allow, and makes this question less constructive. If it were to be given to a site that houses experts that deal with the "meat" of what makes the question constructive, it should fare better.

Therefore, ideally this question would be migrated to English.SE.

(Though the only SE site to choose as an option for off-topic closures seems to be the SciFi meta site. We may want to start another meta discussion about this in order to try to include sites that questions frequently migrate toward).

A question migrated doesn't even count as a VTC AFAIK, and the community (as well as the OP I am sure) should be trying to move the question to the site that best fits in order to get the best quality answer.

Comment: Yes. On this theory, we should also close all questions that use the word "mentalist" because, after all, they have the word "list" in them.

Comment: -1. The spirit of the question was clearly asking for the **term** (or for a location of a list) - not for a list of answers.

Comment: If you're having trouble grasping the distinction, think of it in computer terms. The question asked for a Google search query or a URL - NOT the results of the search or the contents of the URL.

Comment: BTW, I agree with the second half of the answer (re: migration), but OP's question was specifically about "list" and not "migration" issues.

Comment: @DVK I agree that the spirit of the question was asking for the term, which as I explained would do best as a migration. The part of the question not asking for the term certainly was asking for a list. Whether they asked for the location of a list or a list itself is immaterial, since asking for locations of lists will be just as non-constructive as for lists themselves. The answer to "is there a list" is almost always "yes" (this is the internet we are talking about). Turning a "yes" answer into good quality would require at least a link to where the list is (thereby providing a list).

Comment: @NominSim - not typically at all, sorry. Typically, for a more complicated list, there are at most 1-3 **canonical** good locations (E.g. Wiki or TVTropes or some niche geek site). And a solution to a good-in-spirit question that has a small element in danger of being list-y is NOT, as JohnO noted, screaming "LIST!" but editing that one element to be explicitly not list.

Comment: This does sound like an English.SE question. The term for a an animal used to describe a person's function seems to be a literary device of some sort.

Comment: I propose an experiment. Go ask about a science fiction term on English.SE, and see how far you get. If they give the question a fair hearing, then I am wrong about them, if it gets closed in 2 hours I am right. Ask what the difference is between a starship and a spaceship is, maybe. We all know what will happen.

Comment: -1, `The only answers it has received thus far here are list answers` - **Incorrect.**  The only answers it has received so far are "Stereotypes of Animals / Animal Stereotypes", and "Totemic / Animal Totem", but with links that include examples that match up with what the OP is looking for.  Neither are list-type answers, nor are they "me, too" answers.